# How to use regex in Bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I am unable to apply a proper [regex](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Special-Regular-Expression-Characters_57344771) on customtarget column in bigquery.

**With normal MSSQL:**

```
SELECT * from mytable where CustomTargeting like = '%u=%'  -- is all okay
```

**With Bigquery(legacy-sql) :**

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(CustomTargeting, r'[^u=\d]') as validate_users
from [project:dataset.impressions_4213_20181112] Limit 10
```

Error:

> Exactly one capturing group must be specified

Update:

Yet couldn't get substring u ='anystring'

[image]

How can I extract data where CustomTargeting ='%u=somestring%'?

Comment: Try `r'u=([0-9]+)'` if you need to extract 1 or more digits after `u=` substring.

Answer (score 13):

For BigQuery Legacy SQL

In `SELECT` statement list you can use
`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)')`

In `WHERE` clause - you can use
`WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)')`

So, you query can look like

```
#legacySQL
SELECT CustomTargeting, REGEXP_EXTRACT(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)') 
FROM [project:dataset.impressions_4213_20181112]
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)')
```

For BigQuery Standard SQL

Same for `SELECT`
But different for `WHERE` - `WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)')`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CustomTargeting, REGEXP_EXTRACT(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)') 
FROM `project.dataset.impressions_4213_20181112`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(CustomTargeting, r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)')
```

> Update - To address provided data example:

Regular expression updated from `r'^u=(\d*)')` to `r'(?:^|;)u=(\d*)')` - hope it is self-descriptive, but if not  - it makes match to be searched either at the begonning of string or after `;`

Comment: Thanks for explaning the contain..but with I am getting only null as output.

Comment: that is because in your question you were using `^u=` where `^` means start of the string. Now - when you added data example  - it is obvious that your `u=` is not at the beginning of string  - so just remove `^` - I will adjust my answer respectively

Comment: did you have chance to try after removing?